# When message is desterilized by masstransit I am getting them in Camel Case instead of Pascal Case

Tags: masstransit

**dynamic** or **Object** Typed attribute from message are stored in camel case.
Consider we have a Message Like following

```
public class UserCreatedEvent
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public dynamic Payload { get; set; }
}

var userCreatedEvent = new UserCreatedEvent 
{ 
    UserName = "HO", 
    Message = "Test",
    Payload = new {Email = "test@gmail.com"}
}
```

It stores this message in rabbit in following way[image]

When it is deserialized I do not access them by `Payload.Email` I have to use `Payload.email`.

My question is how we can get the message without camel casing when it is typed dynamic or object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing this in 2023, nearly 6 years after this has been asked

MassTransit v8 allows you to inject the JsonSerializerOptions to override the camelCase, like this:
`cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(_ => new JsonSerializerOptions());`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised `dynamic` worked at all, to be honest.

I'd suggest reviewing the guidance for creating message contracts:
http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/message-contracts.html

Anything outside of that, such as using `dynamic` or `object` is sort of at your own risk.

Comment: yes 'dynamic' worked but mass transit makes all attribute to camel case although I have used Pascal case while creating it. It is happening because masstransit stores message by converting it to camel case. what you think?

Comment: Why masstransit serialized object in Camel case? is there any option to change it?